# Power BI Desktop: How to get pie charts to stop refreshing on every edit?

Tags: powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource

I'm working on a Power BI dashboard with lots of pie charts.  The pie charts all show independent data and I have zero need for any interactivity between the charts. Every time I make an edit on the page ALL of the pie charts seem to refresh (the spinner shows over each pie chart).

How do I get the visualizations and data to refresh only on request?

--- EDIT -------------------------------------

It looks like about half of the time (3 seconds out of about 7) is spent rendering a couple of pie charts that have a large number of wedges (~100).

Answer (score 1):

Go to view - sync slicer -> here you can change the interaction between visualizations.

[image]

EDITED:

The second Thing to check. Select one of your charts go to Format -> Edit interactions then select "None" on each ( circle symbol)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help, but it looks like this is not my particular problem (and it looks like this is more for relationships between pages, I don't have any in this report).

Comment: Thanks, that did help but the pie charts with the large number of values is still slowing things down.  It looks like one of the other things that is slowing things down is loading images and buttons for some reason (we have about 5 to 10 of each).